# java swing paint method bonanza

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that separates the application logic from the drawing. There are several color schemes, and I am wondering if this is acceptable programming or if there is a better way to accomplish selecting and drawing the color schemes:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    colorScheme = gameLogic.getColorScheme();

    for (int i = 0; i < gameLogic.getParticleArrSize(); i++) {
        if (colorScheme == 0) {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getParticleColor(i));
            g.fillOval(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i));
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getCurrPartColor());
            g.fillOval(mouseX - mouseOvalRadius, mouseY - mouseOvalRadius,
                    mouseOvalSize, mouseOvalSize);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getCursorColor());
            g.fillOval(mouseX - 19, mouseY - 19, 38, 38);
        } else if (colorScheme == 1) {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getParticleBorderColor(i));
            g.fillOval(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i) - 3,
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i) - 3,
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i) + 6,
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i) + 6);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getParticleColor(i));
            g.fillOval(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i));
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getCurrPartColor());
            g.fillOval(mouseX - mouseOvalRadius, mouseY - mouseOvalRadius,
                    mouseOvalSize, mouseOvalSize);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getCursorColor());
            g.fillOval(mouseX - 19, mouseY - 19, 38, 38);


        } else if (colorScheme == 2) {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i) - 3,
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i) - 3,
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i) + 6,
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i) + 6);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getParticleColor(i));
            g.fillOval(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i));
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(mouseX - mouseOvalRadius - 2,
                    mouseY - mouseOvalRadius - 2,
                    mouseOvalSize + 4,
                    mouseOvalSize + 4);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getCursorColor());
            g.fillOval(mouseX - 19, mouseY - 19, 38, 38);

        } else if (colorScheme == 3) {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fill3DRect(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i) - 2,
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i) - 2,
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i) + 4,
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i) + 4, true);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getParticleColor(i));
            g.fillRect(gameLogic.getParticleXCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleYCoor(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i),
                    gameLogic.getParticleSize(i));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(mouseX - mouseOvalRadius,
                    mouseY - mouseOvalRadius,
                    mouseOvalSize,
                    mouseOvalSize);
            g.setColor(gameLogic.getCursorColor());
            g.fillRect(mouseX - mouseOvalRadius + 7,
                    mouseY - mouseOvalRadius + 7,
                    mouseOvalSize - 14,
                    mouseOvalSize - 14);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an abstract color scheme class, which would declare methods for drawing individual game objects (implementations would do so using different shapes or colors). The `paintComponent` method you posted would then just fetch the current color scheme and delegate all drawing to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the [LookAndFeel concept in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).  It allows you to define different color schemes, and gives you a framework for ensuring that all components have a similar look.